# Position elements on webpage via CSS or Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

[image: Diagram]

What is the best way or how do I position elements as shown in the diagram on a webpage to look like this. I tried absolute positioning but I dont know if that would work in a responsive environment and bootstrap seems not able to do this. Any ideas on how to do this positioning and layout?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the stackoverflow education. Yes i did try absolute positioning but without testing on all available devices I'm not certain that's the best way to do it. I'm not looking fot a solution or someone to do my work...all i need is pointers on how best to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could easily be done using both, and take full advantage of bootstraps responsive framework.

Just style the columns as needed and absolutely position circles.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using CSS padding’s or margins? W3Schools has great tutorials on how to position elements. Here’s one about using margins and padding is on the next page. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp